# The period length of the decimal expression for a rational number $1/n$ has lower bound $1$.

Tags: decimal-expansion

**Theorem**: For an integer $n$ greater than or equal to $2$, the period length of the decimal expression for the rational number $1/n$ is at most $n-1$ and has lower bound $1$.

For the first part I found this page ([Period of the decimal expression for the rational number $\frac{1}{n}$ is at most $n-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140170/period-of-the-decimal-expression-for-the-rational-number-frac1n-is-at-mos)). But for the second part I find no proof.

Comment: Hem, what would be a period of length $0$ ? And there is an ambiguity in the question: period or period length ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The period length. Question edited.

Comment: Doesn't 1/n have period length 1 for n=9? And actually period length 0 for n=2?

Comment: Period length 0 would mean a non-periodic expansion, but expansions of rational numbers are either eventually periodic or terminate, i.e. have periodically repeating 0-s at the end, see [Rational numbers and decimal expansions](https://mathlesstraveled.com/2008/09/07/rational-numbers-and-decimal-expansions/).

Comment: @Conifold: So, the period length for the case where $n=2$ is not zero.

Comment: It is 1 since 0-s repeat: 0.500000000000...

Answer (score 0):

If by "lower bound" you mean the minimum, then yes, it is enough to show that for *one* $n$ you have the period $1$: $\frac{1}{3}=0.33333\ldots$ would suffice.

If by "lower bound" you mean it is the minimum of all accumulation points, i.e. if you need to prove that the period $1$ is reached for infinitely many $n$'s, then it can be done as well. For example:

$$\frac{1}{3}=0.333333\ldots$$
$$\frac{1}{30}=0.033333\ldots$$
$$\frac{1}{300}=0.003333\ldots$$
$$\frac{1}{3000}=0.000333\ldots$$

etc.

(That all excluding "trivial" cases which has a "tail" of zeros, e.g. $\frac{1}{2}=0.500000\ldots$. Not sure how those are regarded in this problem - if you include those, then you are getting an even easier example.)

Comment: The question is for all $n$. I am wondering about the cases similar to $n=2$.

Comment: Ah well ... $1/10=0.100000\ldots$, $1/100=0.010000\ldots$, $1/1000=0.001000\ldots$ etc.